# CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to install APK to device remote Is a directory

Tags: android, build, apk, unity-game-engine

I have no idea with this error.And I can't understand about the "remote".Is that
a catalog or something? When I am using HTC M8 ,I got this error. but it worked on my Nexus 7.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to install APK to device.


Please make sure the Android SDK is installed and is properly configured in the Editor. See the Console for more details. 

C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s "FA451WM07327" install -r "D:\unity專題\WAN0430-1\WAN\Temp\StagingArea\Package.apk"

stderr[

]
stdout[
[  0%] /data/local/tmp/./.
[  0%] /data/local/tmp/./.

adb: error: failed to copy 'D:\unity專題\WAN0430-1\WAN\Temp\StagingArea\Package.apk' to '/data/local/tmp/./.': remote Is a directory
D:\unity專題\WAN0430-1\WAN\Temp\StagingArea\Package.apk: 0 files pushed. 93.5 MB/s (196608 bytes in 0.002s)
rm: /data/local/tmp/.: Is a directory

]
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.ADB.RunInternal (System.String[] command, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.ADB.Run (System.String[] command, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice.Exec (System.String[] command, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice.Install (System.String apkfile, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.PublishPackage.UploadAndStartPlayer (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context, Boolean retryUpload)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.PublishPackage.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a Chinese path, so change this

```
D:\unity專題\WAN0430-1\WAN\Temp\StagingArea\Package.apk
```

with:

```
D:\unity\WAN0430-1\WAN\Temp\StagingArea\Package.apk
```

Comment: Please do not use Chinese for the English Questions.